# a linear operator T

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of a linear operator T on $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that T doesn't have an eigenvalue but $T^2$ is diagonalizable.

I believe that integral operator T does not have eigen values but $T^2$ is diagonalizable.

would someone show me how would I write this thing up? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: All operators have eigenvalues

Answer (score 2):

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}0&\!\!-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: so , $$T^2=
\left[
\matrix
{
-1&0 \\
0&-1 
}
\right]
$$ I know that det($T^2$)= 1. So, how would I show that $T^2$ is diagonalizable

Comment: Look at it? Its in diagonal form.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant you need to find is det($T^2-\lambda I)$. You find that it is equal to $(-1-\lambda)^2$. That means the only eigenvalue of the matrix $T^2$ is -1. (Find the zeros of the determinant)

For it to be diagonalizable, you'd need two eigenvectors linked to the eigenvalue -1. To see if you can find two, you need to find a base of the kernel of the matrix $T^2+I$, which is simply the matrix 0. So the kernel is the whole space, and so you can $(1,0)^t$ and $(0,1)^t$ as it's base.

You have found two eigenvectors, so the matrix $T^2$ is diagonalizable.